# Sinatra Datamapper errors when deploying in Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, datamapper

So i'm trying to deploy my web app on Heroku but I keep getting these errors:

```
app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:163:in require': cannot load such file -- dm-sqlite-adapter (LoadError)
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:163:in load_adapter'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:133:in adapter_class'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:13:in new'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core.rb:230:in setup'
from /app/index.rb:13:in <top (required)>'
from /app/config.ru:1:in require'
from /app/config.ru:1:in block in <main>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in instance_eval'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in initialize'
from /app/config.ru:in new'
from /app/config.ru:in <main>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in eval'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in new_from_string'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in parse_file'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in app'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in wrapped_app'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:147:in start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rackup:23:in load'from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
```

I know that Heroku doesn't work with sqlite, which is why I switched to postgresql as suggested. But that only makes this even weirder since I'm not even using sqlite. :S

Suggestions?

Comment: I’m guessing that line 13 of your `index.rb` has a line something like `DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'sqlite://blah')` and you haven’t got `DATABASE_URL` set.

Comment: Oh wow, you're right. Weird thing is that I searched the file earlier for "sqlite" but couldn't find anything. Now i'm getting some other error while testing locally. I'll check it out more tomorrow and update if i manage to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `dm-sqlite-adapter` is referenced either from your `Gemfile`, either from some other place in the code, probably the place where you configure the  data-mapper. Or maybe it's references in the data-mapper YAML config, if you have one.

Comment: I've removed it from the Gemfile and code, there is no reference to it in any of the files. :S

Comment: nvm It was a search bug or something, now i found it in the code.